# R forecast multivariate regression

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, regression, normal-distribution

A linear multivariate equation Yt=A*Yt-1 + B*Xt + C*Zt +Constant, Xt follows normal distribution with time dependent mean and variance, Xt ~ N(Mean(t), Std(t)). How to create a loop or is there other way to forecast Yt for the next 12 periods in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a spectacular question, you're leaving out a lot of information, but this should help:

```
# define time dependent mean & std for X
xmean <- function(t) 0.5*t
xstd <- function(t) t^(1/3)
xgen <- function(t) rnorm(1, xmean(t), xstd(t))

# define constants (unspecified)
A <- runif(1, min = -1, max = 1)
B <- runif(1, min = -1, max = 1)
C <- runif(1, min = -1, max = 1)

# define Z as Gaussian white noise (unspecified)
zgen <- function(t) rnorm(1)

# set up structure and initialize
y <- numeric(1000)
y[1] <- 0

# define multivariate equation
ygen <- function(t) A*y[t - 1] + B*xgen(t) + C*zgen(t)

# "forecast"
forecasting <- sapply(2:1000, ygen)
```